# Apache2 Virtual Hosts with Ubuntu 15.10 changing DocumentRoot

Tags: permissions, apache2, virtualhost

Background - I just purchased a Ubuntu 15.10 laptop (System76) and moving from Windows 7 (YES! - really enjoy the boot speed and app speed). On Windows, I had an Apache, MySQL and PHP stack and number of Apache Virtual hosts where the DocumentRoot(s) pointed to a directories within a directory I develop php and Java software for different applications and tested it in those virtual hosts, e.g. java_projects, php_ps_projects.

I just got the LAMP stack working on the laptop and Virtual Hosts when they are located in `/var/www`

I tried to point `DocumentRoot` `/home/roy/websites/php_js_projects` and modified `<Directory /var/www/>` to point to `<Directory /home/roy/websites//>` with the same attributes but get:

```
"Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) Server at cnrepperson_com Port 80"
```

I've done a google search and haven't seen any information on making this work or if possible.

Is this possible and if so, what are the necessary steps?

Sure hope this will work as I would hate to have to develop and copy to test location.

Thanks in advance,
Roy

Comment: error.log shows "[Wed Dec 16 12:27:03.624318 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 11216] [client 127.0.0.1:59298] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/roy"

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to ensure that the virtual user/group running apache2 (`www-data`) has at least scan access (x) to all directories in the path. E.g, the following commands (as root):

```
# chmod o+x /home /home/roy /home/roy/websites
# chgrp -R www-data /home/roy/websites/php_js_projects
```

The latter command will make all files in that directory tree be in group `www-data`, which is the group of the apache2. Of course, all published files also need to be group accessible.

Another way, that generally is better I think, is that you add user `roy` to the `www-data` group, and then set it up to keep the published files somewhere under `/var/www`, with a link from `roy's` home directory. In that way you have a more clear separation between "private" and "public" files.

Comment: Thanks Ralph. Tried the first one you mentioned. Might have missed one of the directories  (but double check - I thought), so I got the same 'Forbidden' error. In the second /var/www does a symbolic (ln) to a directory within /home/roy/websites, e.g. /home/roy/websites/php_js_projects or does each file need to be linked?

Comment: Well, apache is normally configured to not follow links. That's why I suggested it to be the opposite way. You may of course change apache's configuration to make it allow links; you'll have to google the details.